# javafx label text color dynamic bindings

Tags: javafx, binding

I have a label `labelSign` which is showing the +ve or -ve sign.

and I have another label `labelValue` and the text color of the label is depending on the text of `labelSign`.

This code is ok if there are two kinds of colors:

`labelValue.textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.when(labelSign.textProperty().isEqualsTo("+ve")).then(Color.GREEN).otherwise(Color.RED));`

How to handle if there are 3 cases of labelSign: `+ve`, `-ve` and `empty` and painting the text of `labelValue` as BLACK if the labelSign is `empty`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Bindings.createObjectBinding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createObjectBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)) to create a binding with the `text` property as dependency.

```
private static Color textToColor(String text) {
    ...
}
```

```
labelValue.textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> textToColor(labelSign.getText()), labelSign.textProperty());
```

This allows you to use an arbitrary algorithm to determine the color based on the text. An update happens everytime one of the dependencies (in this case the `text` property of the `Label`) is updated.

On the other hand you can set an arbitrary text color without changing the displayed result, if the text is empty (= empty string)...